# Make a submit button link to another page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, button, hyperlink, erb

I am using embedded ruby.
So I have the code:

```
<%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

I want to make this button link to another page while submitting the information that was entered into the text field. Is this possible?

If you need any other information just let me know. Thanks

Comment: You would submit the information and then redirect server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller method that the form is submitting to should contain a redirect_to whatever_path.

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html

> redirect_to(options = {}, response_status = {})
>
> Examples:

```
redirect_to action: "show", id: 5
redirect_to post
redirect_to "http://www.rubyonrails.org"
redirect_to "/images/screenshot.jpg"
redirect_to articles_url
redirect_to :back
redirect_to proc { edit_post_url(@post) }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make this button link to another page while submitting the information that was entered into the text field

Yes but you must be careful with your terminology.

It's not the *button* that "submits", it's the *form*.

`HTML` forms send their data to an "action":

```
<form action="url/for/action" method="" />
</form>
```

This "action" is the URL which will process the data/request.

In every server-side language/framework, there is functionality to handle inbound data from HTML. In order to *redirect* to another URL, you have to first ensure you're *processing* the data correctly:

```
#app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      # manage request here
   end
end
```

Only *after* the request has been processed should you "redirect".

Even then, you're not *redirecting* in the standard sense, you're invoking a new request from the server - taking the browser to the new resource.

So you may end up with the following:

```
#app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      if [[conditions for login]]
         redirect_to [[path]]
      else
         redirect_to [[path]]
      end
   end
end
```

The *redirect* will actually be your browser to open a new request with the respective `[[path]]`. The request will have the `session` populated, allowing your application to authenticate the user session etc.